# Why does the `time` Bash builtin write to stderr?

Tags: bash

```
[fakename]$ { time true; } 2> test.log 
[fakename]$ cat test.log

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

It seems that `time` is writing to standard error. I've tried redirecting other file descriptors; that always results in the time being printed.

I am led to the conclusion that `time` writes to stderr. Why is this the case?

Comment: Because you might want to *use* the standard output of the command being `time`d. If it wrote to standard output it would mess up the output of the command.

Comment: Not to be cheeky, because [that is the way it is documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)? Can you make a case why it should not be to stderr?

Comment: @dawg Oh. I did not know of that documentation. I was looking at `help time`, (well, I am also using the builtin one, not time(1)) which didn't provide much helpful information. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexP Ahh. Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because writing to stdout would make it impossible to time **pipes**. The time output would vanish in the pipe and might cause errors further down the pipe due to the unexpected input.

Comment: I don’t believe your remark about vanishing is correct. Even if time wrote to stdout, it would write to the stdout at the end of the pipe. I mean, it writes to the stderr at the end of the pipe. As time is a builtin, I believe it operates on different rules.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Two "different" stdouts? How would you redirect the timing result to a file then?

Comment: You would redirect it as normal, applying the redirection to the end of the pipe. All I’m saying is that it won’t get “eaten up” in the pipe, as you suggest.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 But redirecting the end of the pipe redirects the stdout of the last program in the pipe. I think there will always be an ambiguity.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. It seems that the way to go with this is to put a `time` builtin in a command group, and then redirect the group. Redirecting the end of the pipe does nothing. Just try `time echo hello 2> temp.txt`, and observe that the timing information is still printed.